# powershell 2.0 unable to get Internet Explorer logs

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, event-log

When I try to run cmd get-eventlog -list on win2003 std in powershell V2.0.
It gives me the following output

```
 Max(K) Retain OverflowAction        Entries Log
 ------ ------ --------------        ------- ---
 16,384      0 OverwriteAsNeeded         117 Application
 512      7 OverwriteOlder              0 Internet Explorer
 20,480      0 OverwriteAsNeeded           0 Microsoft-Windows-Forwarding/Operational
 16,384      0 OverwriteAsNeeded         136 Security
 16,384      0 OverwriteAsNeeded         173 System
 15,360      0 OverwriteAsNeeded          83 Windows PowerShell
```

When try to run get-eventlog "Internet Explorer", it gives me Error

```
Get-EventLog : No matches found
At line:1 char:13
+ get-eventlog <<<<   $event
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (:) [Get-EventLog], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetEventLogNoEntriesFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetEventLogCommand
```

Can someone help me resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the exception because it's empty, **BUT** you can still get the object by doing this:

```
$ieLog = get-eventlog -list | where-object {$_.Log -eq "Internet Explorer"}
```

To verify that you really did get the correct log, try writing something in there:

```
$ieLog.Source = "Testing"
$ieLog.WriteEntry("Write Succeeded")
```

Comment: $ieLog.WriteEntry("Write Succeeded")

Answer (score 0):

It's simply because your log was empty at the moment !